# How to change the color of a line in a HTML page containing a specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to change the color of a line in a HTML page(text  in a pre>) Containing A specifique word
for example i want to change the color a any line containig "ERROR" and "Erreur"

```
2014/05/22 02:27:02 - X.0 - Finished processing 
2014/05/22 02:27:02 - DSA.0 - Finished processing 
2014/05/22 02:27:03 - Block.0 - Finished processing 
2014/05/22 02:27:03 - Errors CustomerGroupDimEU.0 
2014/05/22 02:27:03 - Old = New ?.0 - Finished processing 
2014/05/22 02:27:03 - Exists = 0.0 - Finished processing
```

this code replace only the word

```
(function ($) {
    var thePage = $("body");
    thePage.html(thePage.html().replace(/Error/ig, '<span style="color: red;font-weight: bold;">Error</span>'));
})
```

Comment: how do you define a line on an HTML page?

Comment: its a string in a <pre>

Comment: the whole text is between <pre> using  white-space to separates lines

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vahor/1 demo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex was tricky. But here is your desired output :)

```
 (function($) {
    var thePage = $("body"); 
    thePage.html(thePage.html().replace(/(^.*\b(Errors)\b.*)$/igm, 
     '<span style="color: red;font-weight: bold;">$1</span>'));
    })(jQuery);
```

If you want to match more keywords:

```
/(^.*\b(Errors|Error|Erreur)\b.*)$/igm
```

You can keep on adding the keywords with `|`

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vahor/1)**

Comment: You can put several keywords in the regex: `/(^.*\b(Error|Errors|Erreur)\b.*)$/igm`

Comment: /(^.*\b(Errors|Error|Erreur)\b.*

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<pre>2014/05/22 02:27:02 - X.0 - Finished processing </pre>
<pre>2014/05/22 02:27:02 - DSA.0 - Finished processing </pre>
<pre>2014/05/22 02:27:03 - Block.0 - Finished processing</pre>
<pre>2014/05/22 02:27:03 - Errors CustomerGroupDimEU.0 </pre>
<pre>2014/05/22 02:27:03 - Old = New ?.0 - Finished processing </pre>
<pre>2014/05/22 02:27:03 - Exists = 0.0 - Finished processing </pre>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("pre:contains('Error')").css({"color": "red", "fontWeight": "bold"});
})
</script>
```

Comment: The hole text is between <pre> not every line separated